# Automatic Return Type for Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers, return

I hope the headline isn't too confusing. What I have is a class `StorageManager` containing a list of objects of classes derived from `Storage`. Here is an example.

```
struct Storage {};                         // abstract

class StorageManager
{
private:
    map<string, unique_ptr<Storage>> List; // store all types of storage

public:
    template <typename T>
    void Add(string Name)                  // add new storage with name
    {
        List.insert(make_pair(Name, unique_ptr<Storage>(new T())));
    }

    Storage* Get(string Name)              // get storage by name
    {
        return List[Name].get();
    }
};
```

Say `Position` is a special storage type.

```
struct Position : public Storage
{
    int X;
    int Y;
};
```

Thanks to the great answers on my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109356/how-to-pass-a-class-as-parameter/13109493) the `Add` function already works. What I want to improve is the `Get` function. It reasonable returns a pointer `Storage*` what I can use like the following.

```
int main()
{
    StorageManager Manager;
    Manager.Add<Position>("pos");    // add a new storage of type position

    auto Strge = Manager.Get("pos"); // get pointer to base class storage
    auto Pstn = (Position*)Strge;    // convert pointer to derived class position

    Pstn->X = 5;
    Pstn->Y = 42;
}
```

It there a way to get rid of this pointer casting by automatically returning a pointer to the derived class? Maybe using templates?

Comment: if `Storage` is to be base class, then please give it a virtual destructor.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will use that in my real code.

Comment: Note: the idea of using `List[Name]` will cause embarrassment. For `map` and `unordered_map`, `operator []` will create the value (calling the default constructor) if it is not present already. Therefore, if you try to `Get` with a name that does not exist, the pointer is created, leading to a "leak" of elements.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The good thing is that BigBoss provided a better solution to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
template< class T >
T* Get(std::string const& name)
{
    auto i = List.find(name);
    return i == List.end() ? nullptr : static_cast<T*>(i->second.get());
}
```

And then in your code:

```
Position* p = Manager.Get<Position>("pos");
```

Comment: @Xirdus I don't see how that can be improved. You use type erasure and still want the static type? You will need to say it?

Comment: It would be better to use `dynamic_cast` here rather than `static_cast`. Using `static_cast` for downcasting is playing with fire -- and with undefined behavior.

Comment: This is better, at least a bit. But of course it would be much better to don't have to specify the type at all (in the main function).

Comment: @sharethis: that's what you get when you try to reinvent the type system... you were told this would happen [the last time you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927444/let-a-class-store-unknown-data) :)

Comment: @DCoder. You've got me there ;-) And my today's system is much better then what I had. But the time comes when I reinvent the type system completely ;-)

Comment: @DavidHammen `Storage` base class is not `virtual` so we can't use `dynamic_cast` here

Comment: @BigBoss: It was specified in the question that `Storage` is abstract, which in C++ means that the class has at least one pure `virtual` method. I do hope the OP meant it...

Comment: @sharethis According to standard C++, in `dynamic_cast<T>(v)`, `v shall be a pointer to or an lvalue of a polymorphic type`. And in your case if your base class is not a `polymorphic` type(has no `virtual` function) at best case `dynamic_cast` work like `static_cast`

Comment: @MatthieuM. I see nothing about `abstract` except in front of an `struct` that is not `abstract`, so I think may be he named hist class `abstract` while it is not

Comment: @BigBoss: there is a comment `// abstract`. I am just hoping he did not see fit to include the whole code because it was unrelated to the issue.

Comment: @BigBoss: You appear to be confusing virtual inheritance and inheritance from a base class that has at least one virtual method. The question specified that `Storage` is an abstract class, and in the context of C++ this means that `Storage` has at least one pure virtual method. If that is the case, you had best use `dynamic_cast`. If it isn't the case, the questioner should rethink the use of the term abstract, and should also rethink the entire inheritance scheme.

Comment: @BigBoss, Matthieu M, David Hammen. The class `Storage` has a virtual destructor.

Comment: @sharethis I'm writing C++ program for more than 10 years and never need `dynamic_cast` but if your class has a `virtual` destructor(is polymorphic) you should use `dynamic_cast` if it is needed by your design. That depend on your logic and whether you can detect type of your item by your code logic or your should detect it at runtime using `dynamic_cast`. And beside that your class is not `abstract` if only have a `virtual` destructor, an `abstract` class is one with at least one `pure virtual` function.

Comment: @BigBoss. Then my class is not abstract and also shouldn't not be. It is only a data container. There is no need for any function inside the storage class and its derivatives.

Comment: @DavidHammen I never confused by the meaning of polymorphic class, but as you can see in latest comment of `sharethis` his/her class is not `abstract` and what in my comments or answer cause you think that I confused with `virtual` inheritance and polymorphic class?

Comment: @sharethis I never say it should be, but it was a conversation in comments that if you read them you can understand why I say your class is not `virtual` but I'm certain that your class can serve you correctly for your purpose :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what you can do for your `Get` member function besides what @BigBoss already pointed out, but you can improve your `Add` member to return the used storage.

```
template <typename T>
T* Add(string Name)                  // add new storage with name
{
   T* t = new T();
   List.insert(make_pair(Name, unique_ptr<Storage>(t)));
   return t;
}

// create the pointer directly in a unique_ptr
template <typename T>
T* Add(string Name)                  // add new storage with name
{
  std::unique_ptr<T> x{new T{}};
  T* t = x.get();
  List.insert(make_pair(Name, std::move(x)));
  return t;
}
```

**EDIT** The temporary prevents us from having to `dynamic_cast`.
**EDIT2** Implement MatthieuM's suggestion.

You can also further improve the function by accepting a value of the
type to be inserted, with a default argument, but that might incur an
additional copy.

Comment: Nice improvement. I will use that.

Comment: In general, I would advise against naked pointers. In this very situation there is no risk of leak, but it would better to build the `unique_ptr` right away.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Could you illustrate this idea?

Comment: @sharethis I added something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that this looks like a terrible idea... let's see what we can do to improve the situation.

=> It's a bad idea to require default construction

```
template <typename T>
T& add(std::string const& name, std::unique_ptr<T> element) {
    T& t = *element;
    auto result = map.insert(std::make_pair(name, std::move(element)));
    if (result.second == false) {
        // FIXME: somehow add the name here, for easier diagnosis
        throw std::runtime_error("Duplicate element");
    }
    return t;
}
```

=> It's a bad idea to downcast blindly

```
template <typename T>
T* get(std::string const& name) const {
    auto it = map.find(name);
    return it != map.end() ? dynamic_cast<T*>(it->second.get()) : nullptr;
}
```

But frankly, this system is quite full of holes. And probably unnecessary in the first place. I encourage you to review the general problem an come up with a much better design.

Comment: +1, and +more if I could. All in all, this is just a bad idea.

Comment: Maybe I will understand why this is a horrible idea sometimes. But for now I will go with this approach and it is exactly what I wanted to have.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a pointer or reference to an object of some class, all you know is that the actual runtime object it references is either of that class *or of some derived class*.  `auto` *cannot* know the runtime type of an object at compile time, because the piece of code containing the `auto` variable could be in a function that is run twice -- once handling an object of one runtime type, another handling an object with a different runtime type!  The type system can't tell you what exact types are in play in a language with polymorphism -- it can only provide some constraints.

If you know that the runtime type of an object is some particular derived class (as in your example), you can (and must) use a cast.  (It's considered preferable to use a cast of the form `static_cast<Position*>`, since casts are dangerous, and this makes it easier to search for casts in your code.)

But generally speaking, doing this a lot is a sign of poor design.  The purpose of declaring a base class and deriving other class types from it is to enable objects of *all* of these those types to be treated the same way, without casting to a particular type.

- If you want to always have the correct derived type at compile time without ever using casts, you have no choice but to use a separate collection of that type.  In this case, there is probably no point deriving `Position` from `Storage`.
- If you can rearrange things so that everything that a caller of `StorageManager::Get()` needs to do with a `Position` can be done by calling functions that don't specify `Position`-specific information (such as co-ordinates), you can make these functions into virtual functions in `Storage`, and implement `Position`-specific versions of them in `Position`.  For example, you could make a function `Storage::Dump()` which writes its object to `stdout`.  `Position::Dump()` would output `X` and `Y`, while the implementations of `Dump()` for other conceivable derived classes would output different information.
- Sometimes you need to be able to work with an object that could be one of several essentially unrelated types.  I suspect that may be the case here.  In that case, [`boost::variant<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/variant.html) is a good way to go.  This library provides a powerful mechanism called the Visitor pattern, which allows you to specify what action should be taken for each of the types that a `variant` object could possibly be.

Comment: I agree. In general I'd much rather see the casts in the code rather than hiding them behind some mechanism. It's better not to have to use casts at all. Sometimes it is hard to avoid using casts as there are valid use cases for reflection. Even when the usage is justified, those casts should be exposed.

Comment: Your suggestions appear reasonable but there are strong reasons why I decided to use that design. Every of your suggestions to improve the code would completely eliminate these benefits. However thanks for your detailed answer.