# Array of Structures (AoS) vs Structure of Arrays (SoA) on random reads for vectorization

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, vectorization, cpu-cache

My question is in regard of the following phrase from the book:

> Unfortunately, the SoA form is not ideal in all circumstances. For
>   random or incoherent circumstances, gathers are used to access the
>   data and the SoA form can result in extra unneeded data being read
>   into cache, thus reducing performance. In this case, use of the AoS
>   form instead will result in a smaller working set and improved
>   performance. Generally, though, if the computation is to be
>   vectorized, the SoA form is preferred.

My *guess* on why AoS may result in better performance is when different, or better all, fields in the same structure are participating in the single vectorization run.

Example (just a concept, no concrete, or working code at all):

```
/*Note that the types of data I maintain the same intentionally, 
  to simplify discussion*/
struct Data {
     float mean; 
     float distribution[10]
}
```

and define array of those got *randomly* from some data source

`Data aos[5];`

now, if during the vectorization loop I do something like:

```
float* dataPtr =  &(aos[0].mean);

#pragma simd
for(int i=0; i< 60; i++)
{
   const float mean = (*dataPtr);
   /*do something with mean */

   dataPtr++;

   /*do something with distribution */
}
```

this will result in better performance, cause in case of a SoA, I will push on cache line more information that I may actually require during this computation. Some CPU pre-caching ? That in case of AoS results in better performance instead.

Are my assumption correct, or there is something else ?

Comment: Horrid three letter acronyms: SoA = Structure of Arrays, AoS = Array of Structures.

Comment: @HansPassant: that's how they called, and writing complete names down makes title too long and not less ugly.

Comment: @Tigran: Defining the terms once, for the benefit of those who don't know your book's terminology, doesn't take long.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: it's no my book at all, but general way to refer to those structures. anyway, changed title of the question.

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641580/what-is-data-oriented-design

Comment: @NeilKirk: more or less what I wrote here about data locality and reason why in some cases AoS may result in better performance.

Comment: How is `i` actually used together with `dataPtr` in your example? As it is written there is no parallelization with respect to `Data` object. I assumed you want to do something like `dataPtr[i]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can parallelize your program in two ways: horizontally and vertically. I think you are mixing those two approaches.

Horizontal parallelization treats each lane in your SIMD unit as a separate "thread" working on a different data. Vertical parallelization takes whole SIMD unit working on the same data object, trying to benefit from its inner multi-dimensionality.

To give a concrete example: consider you have 2 arrays `X` and `Y` of 3D vectors that you want to add.

- Horizontal approach: each lane of the SIMD unit would do:

  ```
  for(idx = 0; idx<size; idx+=SIMD_size) {
      ... = X[idx+laneid].x + Y[idx+laneid].x;
      ... = X[idx+laneid].y + Y[idx+laneid].y;
      ... = X[idx+laneid].z + Y[idx+laneid].z;
  }
  ```
- Vertical approach: each lane of the SIMD unit takes a different component of the *same* vector:

  ```
  for(idx = 0; idx<size; idx+=1) { 
      ... = X[idx].coord(laneid) + Y[idx].coord(laneid);
  }
  ```

Vertical approach is easier to implement. In fact, compilers are trying to auto-vectorize already. The problem is that as the width of the SIMD unit is growing, the implementation cannot benefit from it. If you switch from 4-wide to 16-wide SIMD, you are still adding up only 3 numbers in parallel of your 3D vector.

Horizontal approach is harder. You usually have to handle diverging branches, function calls, etc... and - you want to reorganize your data into Structure-of-Arrays - so that the corresponding fields of your different data object are next to each other in memory.

---

Now, back to your question: SoA makes sense *only* if you do horizontal parallelization. When each lane is access the same field of different object, SoA  allows to replace an expensive gather instruction with a better aligned single memory fetch.
If you try to do vertical, as in your example in the question - no one would even consider doing SoA in the first place - accessing multiple fields of same object would cause "gather".

However, with random access, SoA may not be the best option even if you do horizontal parallelization. First, you get no benefit of having SoA because you still need to do the expensive gather. However, as your fields of the same object are spread across the memory, each load is going to hit a different cache lane. Not only it increases the usage of memory bandwidth, it may also cause cache thrashing.
This is why SoA are not that efficient with random access.

A better solution is to have a hybrid approach: You pack your data in an Array-of-Structures-of-Arrays-of-SIMD-with-size. But that is another story...

Comment: Might want to mention the pathological case with SoA -- where two components of the same logical structure have cache line contention (read from one causes another one to unload)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you seem to understand the situation.

If you read several values from the same structure, then the CPU will only need to fetch as many cache lines as it needs for those structure members - perhaps just one, if the structure members are nicely laid out. So the cache might look like this (where `v` are the values you want, and empty slots are other values)

```
line 1: | v |   | v | v |   |   | v |   |
```

If those values each have to be read from a separate array, then it will have to fetch a whole cache line for each value. So the cache might look like

```
line 1: |   |   | v |   |   |   |   |   |
line 2: |   |   |   |   | v |   |   |   |
line 3: |   | v |   |   |   |   |   |   |
line 4: |   |   | v |   |   |   |   |   |
```

If you're working through the array in order, then that's good - you'll soon be needing the extra values that were fetched.

However, if you aren't working in order (in the book's words, you're in "random or incoherent circumstances"), then fetching more than you need each time will waste space in the cache, and you'll end up using more memory bandwidth than if the needed values were together in a structure.